# List item arrangement in python

Tags: python

I am looking for an efficient way to transform a given list into another list **with degree n**

here is input:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
n = 3
```

And favorable output is this:

```
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7], [7]]
```

It is basically like every element in resulting list is made of n consecutive elements from the given list except elements at starting and ending `n-1` indices: `1, 2, 6, 7` in this example

Also for integer n, `1 <= n <= len(lst)` is essential

Comment: how efficient? Because you could just make a loop and go through the elements one by one

Comment: does it includes list like `[2,1], [3,2,1]`?

Comment: Related: the `sliding_window` function presented in the [recipes section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) of the `itertools` documentation. (Not an exact solution, as it doesn't include the shorter sublists at either end of the sequence.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a comprehension with appropriate slices:

```
def chunks(lst, n=3):
    return [lst[max(i,0):i+n] for i in range(1-n, len(lst))]

chunks([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
# [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7], [7]]
chunks([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4)
# [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5], [5]]
chunks([1, 2], 2)
# [[1], [1, 2], [2]]
chunks([1, 2, 3], 1)
# [[1], [2], [3]]
```

A more elegant version of this [sliding window](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) uses a [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) (as pointed out by @chepner in the comments):

```
from collections import deque

def chunks(lst, n=3):
    window = deque(maxlen=n)
    for x in lst:
        window.append(x)
        yield list(window)
    while len(window) > 1:
        window.popleft()
        yield list(window)
```

Comment: Nope, than you would always yield an empty window at the end